# DreamFactory: Unknown user permisson Manage Sandbox on system Admin Profile

Tags: migration

I am getting following error while doing migration using Dream Factory between sandboxes:

```
Unknown User Permisson : Manage Sandbox
```

Answer (score 0):

As per salesforce docs

> Users no longer need the “Modify All Data” permission to create,
>   refresh, activate, and delete sandboxes. Instead, users need the new
>   “Manage Sandbox” permission to create, refresh, activate, and delete
>   sandboxes.
>
> With the “Manage Sandbox” permission, users can manage sandboxes
>   without compromising your control over data security, access
>   management, and more.
>
> Users who have the “Modify All Data” permission automatically get the
>   “Manage Sandbox” permission with Winter ’16.

[Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000228356&language=en_US)

So in your case check if current user has Modify all data permission available. And if not you need to assign them this permission.